# Matrix Spark, change the values in Java code

Tags: java, matrix, apache-spark

I work now with the class [DenseMatrix of Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/DenseMatrix.html). I can change the value in the Matrix, if I convert it back to the Array. Some example code:

```
DenseMatrix TestMatrix = new DenseMatrix(n, m, someInputArray);
...
double[] Test = TestMatrix.toArray();
Test[0] = 5;
DenseMatrix TestMat = new DenseMatrix(n, m, Test);
```

Is it possible to replace value(s) in the initial matrix without to convert it back to the Array? Sorry, if I overlooked something in API...

Some additional remark:

```
TestMatrix.apply(0,0) = 5;
```

doesn't work

Comment: I believe that DenseMatrix is immutable. You can't do what you are trying to in unless you are creating a transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you can change the matrix via

```java
matrix.update(0, 0, 5);
```

In Scala this is not possible, though. There the `update` method is set to `private[mllib]` and thus not accessible. I assume that the package private modifier cannot be properly translated to Java and thus you can change `DenseMatrix` even though in Scala it is immutable.